# Position div tags using css

Tags: php, css, html, position

I created a php page that contains a div tag that contains a PHP code that get links from database, then shows an images, So now when it view the images in the div tag it shows the images vertically but I want it to shows me the images horzintilly, that's my code

```
<div class="pppi" style="width: 780px; height: 318px;overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
 <?php
 $msqlq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pictures` WHERE `to` = '$id'");
 while($fetchmsq = mysql_fetch_array($msqlq)){
 $pic = $fetchmsq['name'];
 $pics = "<div class='justprofile'><img src='uploaded/$pic'>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
 echo $pics;
 }
 ?>
</div>
```

So that shows me like this
[image]

but I want it to look like this
[image]

How can I fix this problem, when I tried the css using `top` , `right` and `position:absolute` all the images was located to one position and no spaces between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML output from your PHP, you forgot to close the `<div>` element. Change the `$pics` line to this:

```
$pics = "<div class='justprofile'><img src='uploaded/$pic'></div>";
```

In your CSS, do:

```
.justprofile {
    float: left;
}
```

You may add space between the images by specifying a margin, like this:

```
.justprofile {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

append to your .css file. For align use `float` and a little space between images use `margin-right`

```
div.justprofile {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You neeed to add into your div that contain the image `float:left` inside the style (or in the class) to display elements horizontally.
Try this:

```
<div class="pppi" style="width: 780px; height: 318px;overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto;">
 <?php
 $msqlq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pictures` WHERE `to` = '$id'");
 while($fetchmsq = mysql_fetch_array($msqlq)){
 $pic = $fetchmsq['name'];
 $pics = "<div class='justprofile' style="float:left;"><img src='uploaded/$pic'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
 echo $pics;
 }
 ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

The besto solution is to put inside your class the floating
like this n your css:

```
.justprofile{
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to float anything. `<img>` tags behave like inline by default. Just remove your `<div>` code:

```
$pics = "<img src='uploaded/$pic'>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

Or, if you want to use the `float` property of CSS as others pointed out, do not forget to close your `div`s:

```
$pics = "<div class='justprofile'><img src='uploaded/$pic'></div>";
```